# ASP.NET Web API set custom status code

Tags: asp.net, header, asp.net-web-api

I have the following `Api Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public User Create(User user)
{
    User user = _domain.CreateUser(user);
    //set location header to /api/users/{id}
    //set status code to 201
    //return the created user
}
```

It seems like we have to depend on `Request.CreateResponse(..)` and change the signature of the controller so as to return `IHttpActionResult`.

I do not want to change the method signature as it is very useful for the documentation purpose. I am able to add the `Location` header using `HttpContext.Current.Response...` but not able to set the status code.

Anybody has any better idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using a custom (other) return type outside of void, HttpResponseMessage, and IHttpActionResult - it's harder to specify the status code. See [Action Results in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results).

From [Exception Handling in Web API.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) If you want to stick with not modifying the return type then this might be something you can do to set the status code:

```
[HttpPost]
public User Create(User user)
{
    User user = _domain.CreateUser(user);
    //set location header to /api/users/{id}

    //set status code to 201
    if (user != null)
    {
        //return the created user
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));        
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a good answer. it doesn't deserve a downvote because it does exactly what it says, but throwing exceptions to get the desired behavior here is WAY hacky.

Comment: Use an exception to indicate a normal result is not a reasonable answer.

Comment: From the two articles, it is the recommended way by www.asp.net to set a specific status code and return a custom object.